# How can I build a versatile high voltage translator with an output in the negative and positive range?

Tags: level-shifting, level-translation

Looking for advice on how to build an adjustable voltage translator. Input is standard 1V8 logic, but output HIGH is in a selectable range of +3 to -3V, while output LOW is way down in a selectable range of -15 to -21V.

Cannot find any any off-the-shelf solutions to this. Input frequency range on order of 100k square, output needs to drive upwards of 100pF. Opamps are likely to be unstable at this voltage and cap load. Ideas on types of circuits that can be used here?

[image]

**EDIT**

Output side IO levels are supplies that can be set on-the-fly during operation, so the level translator needs output compliance in the shown ranges. They don't track, they are individually setable. Fast enough slew needed to reliably operate at 100k given the output swing.

Comment: The voltages on the right side, are those supply voltages? What supply voltages are available. Basically I would need to know a bit more about the circuitry connected to the right side of this level translator. The left side is clear to me.

Comment: Ditto the above. You need to specify what power supplies are available.

Comment: and specify min. slew rate for Ioh,Iol @ 100pF

Comment: What is the compliance current requirements of the output? Basically,. I see a 6 V span for both outputs, so that suggests, if the outputs can track together, that you need an adjustable ground reference. Which can be done. But do the outputs track? Or are they independently settable?

Comment: A comparator should work fine.

Comment: Folks, I think he means independently "adjustable design", not output tolerance , which is not hard but custom, but specs need tolerances for  duty cycle, load , rise time, power available etc

Comment: "Opamps are likely to be unstable at this voltage and cap load. " First off, probably not, or at least nothing you can't work around. More importantly, @CL. made the important point: use a comparator. Since this will not be used closed-loop, it will not have obvious stability issues. And until you provide proposed power supply voltages, any detailed discussion is not going to go well.

Comment: Also, what load impedance are you looking to drive?

Answer (score 1):

Use an optoisolated gate driver. The isolation is kind of wasted, but much easier than cobbling together your own solution. https://www.digikey.com/products/en/isolators/isolators-gate-drivers/906

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Is this question for me? Wrong post maybe?

Comment: Sorry, it was intended for the OP. I've deleted.

Answer (score 0):

How about a video amplifier used as a comparator? I did a quick LTspice simulation with an LT1252 and it looks ok. Not what happen when it is over driven.

[image]

Here is the file: http://dl.free.fr/qbHDzipzS

Comment: Are you sure that V1 is supposed to be -3 volts in this configuration?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Between -3V to +3V, based on OP's specs. -3V is the complicated case for U1 inputs range. That's why R1 to R4 are here.

Comment: OK. But given your biasing, you don't need V4 at all. You can just ground that end and modify R1/R2 a bit.

Comment: True. But in the end, Tek's solution is much better, so I'm leaving this as it is.